# Java Script Regex Is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying this Regex -

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]([a-zA-Z0-9-/&\s)])*/
```

Allow any name which starts with group 1 and also allow repetition of character's from second group.

It doesn't work for following -
a$

I think since it is matching with first character . test () returning true for it.

How to write correct regex for it?

Examples :

abc-  Should Match
abc.  should Match
az-az should match
0a9.0a9 should match
a$  Shouldn't Match
$   Shouldn't Match
abc 1 abc. Should Match
abcz&abc&  Should Match
az# Shouldn't Match
az#az Shouldn't Match
ABC' Should Match
ABC'XYZ-1239 Should Match

Comment: You are not matching a `$`

Comment: The regex clearly does not allow for "$" as a character in the string.

Comment: You did not anchor it at the end: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z0-9\/&\s)-]*$/`

Comment: Also `9-/` does not make sense; the "/" character comes before the "9" character in UTF encoding.

Comment: @Pointy no, *I think since it is matching with first character . test () returning true and for it.* - OP needs *false* for the string. Also, `-` can come after a valid range in a character class in a regex without `u` modifier.

Comment: Oh right, I see that now.